# How can I make a C# class with a constructor and have it return a string?

Tags: c#

I created the following:

```
public class HttpException
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling the class like this:

```
var e = new HttpException() {
    Text = "City not created",
    Message = ex.Message,
    InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException.Message,
    InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message
};
var jsonMsg = JSON.ToJSONString(e);
```

Is there a way I could make it so I can call the class with just the parameters of a text message and the exception and
then have it return a string jsonMsg

Note that the JSON.ToJSONString(e) is an external class that I am using to form a JSON string.

Comment: Why not just override `ToString()` and use `JSON.ToJSONString(e.ToString())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want a constructor like this?

```
public class HttpException 
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    private readonly Exception ex;
    public string Message { get { return this.ex.message; } }
    public string InnerExceptionMessage { get { return this.ex.... } }
    public string InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage { get { return this.ex....} }

    public HttpException(string text, Exception ex)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Exception = ex;
    }
}
```

I still wouldn't put the JSON code in there though, that's a separate concern and you don't normally want to mix serialization code with regular class code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implicit operator to make implicit cast of the class like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        HttpException ex = new HttpException ();
        string text = ex;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public class HttpException 
    {
        public string Text = "goofy";

        public static implicit operator string(HttpException ex)
        {
            return ex.Text;
        }
    }
```

### Remarks:

- The implicit operator doesn't stop to string you can make any cast you want.
- You can use the explicit operator for doing explicit cast `string test = (string)goofy;` which might be somewhat more readable.

### Cons of using implicit operator:

- It's hardly discoverable (It's hard from someone different from yourself to find this "feature" and yourself can forgot about that if you take the code from a month from now.)
- It's make the code more complex to read (someone might thing what the hell is going on here).
- It's error prone.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by zzzzBov, you can simply override the ToString() method.
However, if the only use for this object is to create the json string, I would consider creating the class like this:

```
public class HttpException
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    public static string CreateJsonString(string Text, string Message, 
                                          string InnerExceptionMessage, 
                                          string InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage) {
        return JSON.ToJSONString(new HttpException() {
                                     Text = "City not created",
                                     Message = ex.Message,
                                     InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException.Message,
                                     InnerExceptionInnerExceptionMessage = 
                                     ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message});
   }
}
```

then all you have to write in your code is:

```
var jsonMsg = HttpException.CreateJsonString("City not created", 
                                              ex.Message,
                                              ex.InnerException.Message,
                                              ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message
                                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

[*Implicit operators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx):

```
public static implicit operator string(HttpException exception)
{
    return JSON.ToJSONString(e);
}
```

This implicitly converts an `HttpException` into a string behind the scenes, so now you can do this:

```
string json = new HttpException();
```